# Correct way to disable/override mouse press/click handling for JTree

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtree, key-bindings

I need to have editable `JTree` but editing should be started by double clicking on node or presssing F2  instead of just pressing mouse/clicking on node as it is set by default.

What is the best way to disable handling of mouse press or single mouse click on JTree (or any other similar component like JTable for example) but keeping the selection handling?

I have code for starting editing I just need to turn off JTree starting editing with another events.

Comment: as default, by double clicking node expands.

Comment: Take a look at TreeSelectionModel. That's what I would I do if I were in your place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you need to manage editor of `JTree`, here is simple example:

```
    JTree t = new JTree();
    t.setEditable(true);
    TreeCellRenderer cellRenderer = t.getCellRenderer();
    DefaultTreeCellEditor cellEditor = new DefaultTreeCellEditor(t, (DefaultTreeCellRenderer) cellRenderer){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject arg0) {
            if(arg0 instanceof MouseEvent){
                return ((MouseEvent)arg0).getClickCount() > 2;
            }
            return super.isCellEditable(arg0);
        }
    };
    t.setCellEditor(cellEditor);
```

examine [`DefaultTreeCellEditor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultTreeCellEditor.html) and it's method `isCellEditable(EventObject arg0)`.

Comment: +1 for brutte- force, ....... can be misspeled, because one of event is [about node is selected, reason for my question on Coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/584508/GUI/java/change-DefaultCellEditor-setClickCountToStart-int-DefaultTreeCellEditor), have to test before from TreeSelectionListener

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I had it in front my eyes and did not see that parameter to `isEditable()`.